# Parse REST API Byte upload limit

Tags: javascript, ajax, base64, parse-platform

Is there a limit to the amount of data that can be uploaded to the Byte data type with the Parse REST API?

I have a column to upload Base64 with a Byte data type but when I'm sending the image I get a 413 - entity too large error.  The images I'm uploading are ~700kb but can't seem to find anything about there being a max file size.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is a 128KB max size on PFObject. Any reason you're not using PFFile for this instead?